# How to remove duplicate rows and concatenate values from one column in CSV

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed, scripting

I want to remove duplicate rows from a CSV and concatenate the values of specific column (in this case, column2).

Input

```
ID column2 column3 column4, etc....
1  a       test3   test4
1  r       test3   test4
1  c       test3   test4
2  r       test3   test4
2  o       test3   test4
3  a       test3   test4
4  b       test3   test4
4  c       test3   test4
4  e       test3   test4
```

Expected result

```
ID column2 column3 column4, etc....
1  a|r|c   test3   test4
2  r|o     test3   test4
3  a       test3   test4
4  b|c|e   test3   test4
```

Is it possible with awk?

Comment: Are column 3 and 4 constant?

Comment: @glennjackman There is more than 4 columns. And yes, they are constant.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`, for variable column, for the general case where all the other columns may change.

```
awk -v col=2 -v OFS="\t" '{
    temp=$col
    $col=""
    a[$0]=a[$0]? a[$0] "|" temp: temp
}
END {for (i in a) {
        split(i, b)
        for (j=1; j<=length(b); j++) {
            if (j==col) printf a[i] OFS
            printf b[j] OFS
        }
        printf ORS
    }
}' file |sort -n |column -t
```

This uses an associative array with the line excluding `$col` as index and append to it the value of `$col`.

At the `END` we take care to put `$col` back to its place while printing, by splitting fields to another array.

The order of the output is undetermined and you can pipe it to `sort` for any sorting type per any field. And to `column -t` if you need so.

Comment: the values in other columns can be text (more than one word).

Comment: Then you have to use a delimiter other than tab, when you get your csv data and then set the `awk` field separator accordingly. This `FS` should be also used inside the `split` function above. I don't see why you get tab delimited file if you have plain text as fields.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & column):

```
sed -r '1b;:a;$!N;s/^(\s*\S+\s)(\S+)\s*(\S+\s*\S+\s*)(.*)n\1(\S+)\s*\3/\1\2|\5 \3\4/;ta;P;D' file | column -t
```

Pattern match on all lines except the first and then format the expected result using back references and the column command.

N.B. The first field is stripped of its white space.

Comment: There is more than 4 columns. And no white space in the first one. Thanks.